# Understanding OLD PEEL173 code

Tags: boolean-algebra, programmable-logic, pld

I have some code for a PEEL173 form the early 90's. I would like to understand the logic of this code, but I don't recognize this syntax.

Question 1: Do you recognize the syntax of this language? What is this programming language called?

[image]

Question 2: This is my attempts to decode the first line. Let me know what you think:

My guess: * are AND, + are OR and / are NOT:

```
FUN0 = N AND NOT(F1) AND NOT(F2) AND NOT(F4) ND NOT(F8) AND NOT(F16)
```

And one of the other lines:

```
RE = NOT(FUN0 OR FUN1 OR FUN2 OR FUN5)
```

Best Regards.

Comment: you got it right ... it makes no sense to be different from what you think

Comment: the language could be `APEEL Logic Assembler`

Comment: or it could be `PALASM`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by commenters, it is likely PALASM and my interpretation of the logic is accurate.